# Thousand sprite draws poor performance

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I am writing an application, and I've encountered low fps, I've found that almost all CPU time is consumed by spriteBatch.draw() methods(about thousand calls). So I've created simple drawing app

```
public void render() {
    spriteBatch.begin();
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
        spriteBatch.draw(tex, 0, 0);
    }
    spriteBatch.end();
}
```

The app runs 18fps
when I increase window size so it almost fill the entire screen fps drops to 7!, when the window size in vary small it runs on 60fps, on fullscreen I get 20FPS(1600x900) - better than maximized window
I am using only one texture (512, 512 - png), maxRenderCalls on spriteBatch is 2, 5 on polygonSpriteBatch - both same FPS
disabled blending -> no change, same FPS

1. Is it normal that 2k of sprites drops fps below 20 on desktop? - ( Core i5-3210M Processor(2.50GHz 1600MHz 3MB), NVIDIA® GeForce® GT630M)
2. Is it normal that changing windows size affects the performance?

Comment: The answer to both questions is just "depens on what actuually are you drawing (and how you do it, to a certain degree)".

Comment: Therefore I've tested it on the simplest code I could think of. I don't see any faster method to draw or any room for optimalization. If it does mean that scene cannot draw 1000+ sprites at 30fps, how to make a game? Game needs lots of sprites, particle effects +, logic, + physic.

Comment: Well, there are a lot of unknowns: e.g., how big is each sprite? Drawing 2000 full-screen quads will certainly kill performance on any GPU out there. There is also plenty of potential for optimization: first of all, drop libgdx, and use some decent modern GL features. Avoid a single texture object per sprite, use array textures. Ideally, this can be optimized to a single draw call, GL wise.

Comment: "Drawing 2000 full-screen quads will certainly kill performance on any GPU" - didn't know that.
So it seems like a normal behaviour and there is room for optimalizations. I thought there was something wrong or that libGDX cannot handle more complex scenes.
I'll take a look at open-GL stuff.

Comment: GPUs don't do magic. For example, the GT630M is specified at a texture fillltate at 12.8 GTexel/s. So if you draw 2000 textured fullscreen quads (and have no overdraw preventions like the depth test) at FullHD, the GPU would be under otherwise optimal conditions limited to 3 fps in that scenario. Coming near that would be actually very hard in a real-world scenario, since typically you don't have 100% cache hits for the texture access, which that number basically assumes.

Comment: LibGDX on desktop has no trouble drawing thousands of sprites at 60fps if they reference the same texture like you're doing, provided they are small on the screen. But you're drawing them 512x512 (presumably with a 1:1 pixel scale), so you are hitting a fill rate bottle neck. That also would explain why the FPS drops when you enlarge the window. Change `spriteBatch.draw(tex, 0, 0);` to `spriteBatch.draw(tex, 0, 0, 16, 16);` and you'll hit 60fps easily.

Comment: Yeah, it works, I didn't know that drawing size of the sprite matters, performance-wise.
I thought that it is the texture size, that really matters.
Well is seems, that I need to learn more about OpenGL, no just libGDX.

Comment: What tutorials for openGL should I use, LWJGL or JOGL tutorials?

Comment: Shouldn't matter if you're just learning how OpenGL works. If you switch back to LibGDX, there will not be any relevant difference. LibGDX classes like SpriteBatch mostly hide OpenGL calls but it helps to understand the basics of what it's doing by browsing its source (after you know the basics of Open GL). This site has a lot of basic tutorials for OpenGL ES for iOS and Android. https://www.raywenderlich.com It helped me a lot when I was leaning several years ago. Even the iOS ones were helpful to simply read, not do.

Comment: As for this situation, in simple terms you should think about the vertex and fragment shaders. Each Sprite has four vertices so the vertex program has to be run four times per frame per Sprite. But a 512x512 pixel image (on screen size, not texture size) has to run the fragment shader program 260K times per Sprite per frame! The on screen size definitely matters. The source texture size isn't very relevant to performance if you are using mip mapping. You could easily draw 2000 512x512 textures if you draw them small on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 'll try to answer it myself (feel free to post better answers)

It **is** normal.

The main reson of the performance issue was the size. **Drawing** size really matters, when I draw it at tenth of the size, I get **30fps even with 50 000** sprites!

I can also get slightly more (48fps) when using PolygonSpriteBatch, even with enabled blending!

Also enabling and disabling bleding too often(I have done it 1000+times a frame), can really affects the perfromance negatively.